# Problem in AT+CIPSEND(CTRL-Z) GPRS GMS A6

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, gsm

I am using GPRS GSM A6 with arduino uno to post data to web server. After sending AT commands to module I get OK response after every command,

```
AT+CIPMUX=0

OK
AT+CGATT=1

OK
AT+CSTT="internet","",""

OK
AT+CIICR

OK
AT+CIFSR

10.65.87.210

OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 80

CONNECT OK

OK
AT+CIPSEND

> POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Code/ HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 18

Data=GPS Data Sent
AT+CIPCLOSE

>
```

To terminate AT+CIPSEND you have to send CTRL-Z. I am sending CTRL-Z using this statement in code,

```
Serial.write(0x1A)
```

But the module doesnot respond to this, and treats the next command (AT+CIPCLOSE) as data.

Please Help... Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Also just so you know x-www-form-urlencoded requires + instead of spaces and any non-alphanumeric characters must be percent encoded https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 1):

RTFM: https://github.com/espressif/esp8266_at/wiki/CIPSEND

You need to close the input steam with "+++" to return to command mode.

Answer (score 0):

To terminate AT + CIPSEND just apply the next command:

```
Serial.write(26);
```

or

```
gsm.write(26);
```

where gsm is the UART channel of gsm module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AT+CIPSEND= instead of AT+CIPSEND